# flume load csv files excels to hdfs sink

Tags: excel, csv, hadoop, hdfs, flume

I have configured my Flume source to be of type Spooldir. I have a lot of **CSV files, .xl3 and .xls**, and I want my Flume agent to load all files from the spooldir to HDFS sink. However flume agent return exception

This is my config for flume source:

```
agent.sources.s1.type = spooldir
agent.sources.s1.spoolDir = /my-directory
agent.sources.s1.basenameHeader = true
agent.sources.batchSize = 10000
```

and my HDFS sink :

```
agent.sinks.sk1.type = hdfs 
agent.sinks.sk1.hdfs.path = hdfs://...:8020/user/importflume/%Y/%m/%d/%H 
agent.sinks.sk1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
agent.sinks.sk1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent.sinks.sk1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent.sinks.sk1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
agent.sinks.sk1.hdfs.batchsize =    10000
agent.sinks.sk1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.sk1.serializer = avro_event
agent.sinks.sk1.serializer.compressionCodec = snappy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below configuration for spool dir. Just give the paths of your local file system and HDFS locations in the below configuration.

```
#Flume Configuration Starts
# Define a file channel called fileChannel on agent1
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.type = file 
# on linux FS
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.capacity = 200000
agent1.channels.fileChannel1_1.transactionCapacity = 1000
# Define a source for agent1
agent1.sources.source1_1.type = spooldir
# on linux FS
#Spooldir in my case is /home/hadoop/Desktop/flume_sink
agent1.sources.source1_1.spoolDir = 'path'
agent1.sources.source1_1.fileHeader = false
agent1.sources.source1_1.fileSuffix = .COMPLETED
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.type = hdfs

#Sink is /flume_import under hdfs

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.path = hdfs://'path'
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollSize = 268435456
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollCount = 50000000
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent1.sources.source1_1.channels = fileChannel1_1
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.channel = fileChannel1_1

agent1.sinks =  hdfs-sink1_1
agent1.sources = source1_1
agent1.channels = fileChannel1_1
```

You can also refer to [this blog](https://acadgild.com/blog/loading-files-into-hdfs-using-flumes-spool-directory/) on Flume spool dir for more information.